# Split list of values for select list in Oracle Apex

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-apex

im working on Oracle Apex and im trying to load the result of a list of values into a select list, which is a combobox at the end. My code is the following.

```
select
field1 || ',' || field2 || ',' || field3 as dv, id rv 
from table
where id=1
order by 1
```

This code worked, but not as i need.I need to print the past 3 results in 3 different spaces and NOT with commas in only one line. How could i split that and print them in different lines but in the same select list(combobox) with Oracle Apex.

Hope you can help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if I understood your question, you have a record with three columns and want to display them as three distinct lines.

if so, I'd do like this:

```
 select decode(level, 1, field1
                    , 2, field2
                    , 3, field3) display_value
       ,id return_value /* this will return the same ID for each line, please review the logic */
   from table
  where id = 1
connect by level <= 3
  order by 1
```